# Jenkins pulling plugins returns 404

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-kubernetes

I am using Jenkins with kubernetes and my kubernetes pod is not able to start. I can see this in the log:

```
08:35:39 Failed in the last attempt (curl -sSfL --connect-timeout 20 --retry 3 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/durable-task-plugin.hpi -o /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/durable-task-plugin.jpi)
Failed to download plugin: durable-task or durable-task-plugin
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
08:35:46 Failure (22) Retrying in 1 seconds...
08:35:47 Failed in the last attempt (curl -sSfL --connect-timeout 20 --retry 3 --retry-delay 0 --retry-max-time 60 https://updates.jenkins.io/dynamic-2.248//latest/bootstrap4-api-plugin.hpi -o /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins/bootstrap4-api-plugin.jpi)
Failed to download plugin: bootstrap4-api or bootstrap4-api-plugin
 > authentication-tokens depends on credentials:1.22
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 20526 milliseconds
08:35:57 Failure (28) Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

It seems like a lot of plugins are failing to be fetched. Can someone advice how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with updates.jenkins.io There is nothing you can do, but only wait after the issue gets resolved.

The maintainers are explaining the issue:

> The Kubernetes cluster we use on Microsoft Azure is suffering timeouts when trying to mount volumes needed to manage the mirror infrastructure.
> https://github.com/jenkins-infra/jenkins.io/issues/3958